# How to retrieve nested properties along with the id from Azure DocumentDB

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I have some documents stored in documentdb that follow this basic design:

```
{
  "id": "abc123",
  "hiddenField": "XXXXXX",
  "attributes": {
    "x": "7",
    "y": "8",
    "z": "9"
  }
}
```

In this example there are three properties under attributes, but this is not constant in practice.  I want to retrieve it without the hidden field and project the arbitrary number of attributes into the root of the document alongside the id:

```
{
  "id": "abc123",
  "x": "7",
  "y": "8",
  "z": "9"
}
```

With this query I can get x, y, and z into the root:

```
SELECT VALUE c.attributes FROM c
```

Which will produce this result:

```
{
  "x": "7",
  "y": "8",
  "z": "9"
}
```

...but this query is invalid:

```
SELECT c.id, VALUE c.attributes FROM c
```

Which is understandable as the docs do say that you can either list properties OR use the VALUE operator.  Fair enough.

Is there a way to use the JOIN operator or some other projection to end up with the desired result set?

Comment: I'm not sure off the top of my head if this is possible using the SQL Document APIs but it would be quite easy to implement a SPROC that does this transformation for you

Comment: Thanks, that's a good idea.  We're currently doing the parsing in a JavaScript Azure Function so it probably wouldn't be too hard to move it back into the database layer for some efficiencies.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your scenario, I assumed that you could refer to the following query:

```html
SELECT
    c.id,
    c.attributes.x as x,
    c.attributes.y as y,
    c.attributes.z as z
from yourinput c
```

**Sample data:**

```html
[{
  "id": "abc123",
  "hiddenField": "XXXXXX",
  "attributes": {
    "x": "7",
    "y": "8",
    "z": "9"
  }
},{
  "id": "abc456",
  "hiddenField": "XXXXXX",
  "attributes": {
    "x": "1",
    "y": "2",
    "z": "3"
  }
}]
```

**Result:**

[image]

**UPDATE:**

Since the number of `attributes` property in your document is arbitrary, I assumed that you could leverage [user defined functions (UDFs)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/programming#udf) to achieve this purpose as follows:

**udf.fun**

```html
function main(attributes, id) {
    attributes["id"]=id;
    //add your other properties here
    return attributes;
}
```

**Query:**

```html
SELECT
    UDF.fun(attributes,id)
FROM
    [YourInputAlias]
```

Comment: Thanks, but the number of attributes is arbitrary.  I have edited the question to reflect this.

Comment: I have updated my answer based on your scenario, you could refer to it.